# How to use Perl modules without terminal access?

Tags: perl

I am using a web hosting service that only provide FTP access but not terminal (telnet, SSH, etc) access. Perl core is already installed on the server along with a small number of modules (such as LWP::Simple). My script want to use modules that were not installed (such as WWW::Mechanize). Are there any way that I use these modules without normal installation?

Comment: There is a good answer for this somewhere, but I can't find it right now. Essentially if you can run Perl, you can load the CPAN module and make it install stuff in a local lib. I'll try and find that duplicate target later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put package(something.pm) in your folder structure. I personally like to put them in `modules` folder.

Then include it in your script. I did it like that:

```
BEGIN {push @INC, '<path_to_your_project>/modules'};
use <YOUR_PACKAGE>;   <- package name
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Instead of manually messing with `@INC`, you can also just [`use lib`](https://perldoc.pl/lib).

Answer (score 2):

Try http://sf.net/projects/cgipan to install modules without shell access.

[image]

Comment: ... and make sure to deactivate this script after you're done, and if possible protect the script with a password (disclaimer: I'm the author)